# How to obtain and display specific value in Gridview on ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am currently developing an online shopping cart project.

I would like the program to display the `GetTotal()` in a label outside of the GridView.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="C1" Runat="Server">

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" Width="832px"    >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# "../" + Eval("Product_Image") %>' runat="server"  Height="100px" Width="100px"/>

                      </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Series">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Series") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Price") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                  <FooterTemplate>
                    Total Amount:
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# GetUnitPrice(Decimal.Parse(Eval("Product_Price").ToString())*Decimal.Parse(Eval("Product_Quantity").ToString())).ToString("N2")   %>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="l6" runat="server" Text=' <%# GetTotal().ToString("N2") %>'></asp:Label>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true"/>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true"/>

             </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

All values in the GridView are passed on via session from another page, excluding `Price` and `TotalUnitPrice`, where calculations are carried out in the script below:

```
<script runat="server">

decimal TotalUnitPrice;
decimal GetUnitPrice(decimal Price)
{
    TotalUnitPrice += Price;
    return Price;
}
decimal GetTotal()
{
    return TotalUnitPrice;
}

</script>
```

Any ideas on how to do this? The reason is that I would like the program to obtain the value of `GetTotal()`via the label and charge the user based on it.

Comment: The `GridView` will have many rows right? So you will have `TotalUnitPrice` for each product. In that case, you can use a `<asp:CommandField />` and when you select a particular product its `TotalUnitPrice` will be displayed in the label below.

Comment: but then I would need the program to charge the user based on the TotalUnitPrice shown above. maybe using label is not the best way?

Comment: The `TotalUnitPrice` value is already within the `GridView` so you can access it anytime in the back end code. So I guess you won't be needing a separate label to display the price. To display it in the label you have to access the `TotalUnitPrice` from GridView anyway. Instead, you can access it from GridView and then send it to the user directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GetTotal()` in binding in GridView footer Label `16` so you can get it from there and set to outside Label:

```
// check if GridView is not empty
if (GridView1.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    string total = ((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("16")).Text;
    LabelOutside.Text = total;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly, however if I were to access this page when the `GridView` is empty, it throws an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: you can simply perform a check if gridview is empty : `if(GridView1.Rows.Count != 0)`